# How to make UIProgressView work in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to implement the `UIProgressView!`. I am downloading some data from a website and I am not wrapping my head around some of the fundamentals of how to write this code. I have the label called `message` which will be updated when the data is downloaded, but I want to show the progress of the data being downloaded.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //They user types in the city they want to recieve the weather from
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UITextField!

    //The label that is being updated when the data finally reaches the phone
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!

    //The progress bar
    @IBOutlet weak var downloadProgress: UIProgressView!

    //My 'What's the weather?' button
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        //When you touch the button, the keyboard goes away
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        //setting the urlString to the address of the website, it will add the city that you type into the city text field
        var urlString = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") + "/forecasts/latest"

        //Setting the url to the urlString
        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data, response, error) in

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
            var contentArray  = urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")
            var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

            //Updating the message text with the content that I want from the HTML source
            self.message.text = (newContentArray[0] as! String) 
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

self.downloadProgress.progress = 0.0

    }

    func makeMyProgressBarMoving {

        var recievedData : Float
        var expectedTotalSize : Float
        var actual : Float = downloadProgress.progress
        if (actual < 1) {
            downloadProgress.progress = actual + (recievedData/expectedTotalSize)
            [NSTimer .scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, invocation: self, repeats: false)]
        }   
    }
```

Comment: If this is for iOS 9, you might want to read up on the new NSProgress feature.

Comment: This is for iOS 8. Well for now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the progress because you do not *have* any progress. You've implemented the wrong way of downloading the data. Use the other way - the one where you get delegate messages. One of them tells you the progress. In particular, you'll implement

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData {
```

Here you'll accumulate the data in an NSMutableData, and each time, you can compare the size of that accumulated data to the size of the expected total data, and thus you have the basis for updating the UIProgressView.